# running simple basic AJAX with or without xampp on a local file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I browsed few other posts that answers my question but I can't seem to understand  how to solve it.

the problem seems to be that my code is requesting cross domain request; i cant run simple html ajax on file://

so what I did was use xampp to run the program on localhost

this is my directory http://localhost/practice/practice.php

inside this php the code looks like this

```
function ajaxor(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "practice.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();

  alert(xhttp.status);
}
```

php file seems to be running fine but when I alert the xhttp.status it outputs 0 instead of 200.

I'm really stuck and confused. this is my first time trying out AJAX and it hasn't been smooth from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look at the wrong place because you are using the asynchronous version of ajax. All stuff happens, if something happens, inside the function `onreadystatechange`. So put you `alert(xhttp.status);` inside that function under the line `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;`. If all works well you will see a `200` or you will see nothing if an error happens.

```
function ajaxor(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      alert(xhttp.status + " should be 200");
    } else {
      alert(xhttp.status + " en error happend");
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "practice.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

This assumes that all filenames and path's are correct, or course.

Comment: very stupid mistake of me. everything is working fine. should I delete this post?

Comment: I thought it was stackExchanges etiquette to delete bad posts like this.

Comment: If people think it is a bad post they will downvote it. You got one upvote, which is quite rare for such a question here, so...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple states of readyState.

Changes from 0 to 4:

0: request not initialized

1: server connection established

2: request received

3: processing request

4: request finished and response is ready

Your alert is being reached before the readyState reaches its final state and as such before the function can even execute. To be sure try adding an additional alert inside your function like this and see which alert comes first. :)

```
function ajaxor(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    alert("Status 1:"+xhttp.status);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "practice.txt", true);
xhttp.send();

alert("Status 2:"+xhttp.status);
}
```